# Can I use a celery task's send_event instead of update_state for state updates?

Tags: python, celery

While working on a asynchronous task queue for a webserver (built with python and flask), I was finding a way to get the server to actually perform some work once a task update comes in. There is a function for a task that can be used on the client side (`celery.app.task.get`), and one to send updates on the worker side (`celery.app.task.update_state`).

But this requires a result backend to be configured. This is not a problem, perse. But I came across celery events (https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/monitoring.html#real-time-processing).

This apparently allows to omit the result backend. On the worker side, this requires to use the `celery.app.task.send_event` function.

I do not need to send the result of a task to the client (it is a file on a shared volume), or store it in a database, but I do like to receive progress updates (percentage) of the tasks. Is using the event system a good alternative to `update_state()`?